# VBA to Choose Row Based on Two Criteria; One Exact Value and the Other Value is One of Several from a List on Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The code provided will currently copy a row and place it into another sheet if the code finds a row that contains both "OlsonJo" (Value=) in one cell and another cell that contains "UT-*" (Value Like (thx, S. Craner)).

I would like to modify this code to still include Value="OlsonJo" however the second criteria would be from a list.  For example, if the row contains "OlsonJo" and the second criteria equals one of these in the list below (that resides on another sheet in the workbook).

```
UHS-Committee
UHS-Admin-Managing UHS Services
UHS-Admin-Meetings with staff
UHS-Admin-Communicating w/staff
UHS-Admin-Update Lab Test Formul
UHS-Admin-Write Procedure Manual
UHS-Admin-Candidate Interview
UHS-Admin-Consult Emp & Rev Qual
UHS-Admin-Scheduling functions
UHS-Admin-Strategic Lab Plan
UHS-Admin-Budget Planning
UHS-Admin-Equip Select & Acquis.
UHS-Admin-Test Select & Valid.
UHS-Sup/Ment Res/Fell-Sup Pa&Oth
UHS-Sup/Ment Res/Fell-1-1, Did
UHS-Sup/Ment Res/Fell-Sign O Case
UHS-Res/Fell-Interv ACGME pos
UHS-Res/Fell-Oth Act;Ad Res Prog
UHS-QA-Design/Analyze Lab QA Act
UHS-QA-Interpret Qual. Data/Rep
UHS-QA-Rev. Ext PT,QC,QM,& QAP
UHS-QA- Rev Investing Record lab events deviations
UHS-QA-Lab/Hospital Accred Act.
UHS-Autopsy-UHS Patient Autopsy
UHS-Analy-Clin Inform/Analy
UHS-Analy-Clin Inform EPIC Build
UHS-Analy-Proc.Improvem Act
UHS-Analy-Pop Hlth/Interd Coll
UHS-Analy-Clin Lab Util Mngt
```

then copy that row and place it in the designated sheet!

I have not been able to find a tutorial that includes pulling from a list of options.  Again, thank you in advance for your time!

```
Sub FindOlsonUT()   
    Dim i, LastRow
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this line finds the last row used in a sheet.

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:M1000").ClearContents 'this line clears the contents of Sheet2 from A2 to M1000.

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "OlsonJo" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UT-*" Then 'the two criteria are in this line; exactly "OlsonJo" and contains "UT-"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'destination is Sheet 2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you still testing column H for the UHS list?

Comment: Yes I am.  Column H.  Thanks!

Comment: can't you just change `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UT-*" ` to `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-*"`?

Comment: I wish...  In column H of Sheet 1, there are more lines that begin with "UHS-" that don't match the examples I provided.  Those specific tasks are the ones that need to be pulled from the larger data set.  Thank you again!

Comment: How many of the other "UHS-" are there?

Comment: 61 other tasks begin with "UHS-".  Thanks!

Comment: I would simply use the "find" function to check if the value of the cell is in the list. If the result is not null, it's in the list and you can commence copy/paste operations.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the long way around the barn, but it works.  Separated into subs.  One sub looks for all rows with one of 8 or 9 different Value Like "UHS-

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Admin*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Sup/Ment Res/Fell-*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Res/Fell-*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-QA-*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Sup*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Autopsy-UHS Patient Autopsy" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Analy-*" Then
```

and copies those rows to Sheet2.

A second sub separates those tasks into different sheets by user.

```
Sub FindFiebelkornUHSAOA()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this line finds the last row used in a sheet.
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:M1000").ClearContents 'this line clears the contents of Sheet3 from A11 to M1000. 
For i = 11 To LastRow
If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "D").Value = "FiebelkornKr" Then 
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" 
& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Destination is Sheet 3 for rows that contain FiebelkornKr.

Here is the code that achieves the result I am looking for.  Unfortunately, I have to apply this to 40-50 users.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PathDocsTimeSheets()
Call ExtractUHSAOA
Call FindFiebelkornUHSAOA
Call FindFiebelkornUHSClinCare
Call FindGreebonUHSAOA
Call FindGreebonUHSClinCare
End Sub

Sub ExtractUHSAOA()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this line finds the last row used in a sheet.
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A11:M1000").ClearContents f 
Sheet2 from A11to M1000.
For i = 11 To LastRow
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Admin*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Sup/Ment Res/Fell-*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Res/Fell-*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-QA-*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Sup*" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Autopsy-UHS Patient Autopsy" Or 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Analy-*" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'destination is Sheet2
End If
Next i
End Sub


Sub FindFiebelkornUHSAOA()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this line finds the last row used in a sheet.
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:M1000").ClearContents 'this line clears the contents of Sheet3 from A11 to M1000.
For i = 11 To LastRow
If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "D").Value = "FiebelkornKr" Then 
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" 
& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'destination is Sheet 3
End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub FindFiebelkornUHSClinCare()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'this line finds the last row used in a sheet.
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A11:M1000").ClearContents
For i = 11 To LastRow
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "FiebelkornKr" And 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UHS-Clin*" Then 'finds rows that have both "FiebelkornKr" exactly in column D and another cell that contains "UHS-Clin" in column H.
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" 
& Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'destination is Sheet4
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you for the suggestions and comments.